# Supremum and Infimum of the $nth$ Tail

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $x_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$. Find $\inf(T_n)$ and $\sup(T_n)$.

I believe that on this one I'm still having some trouble wrapping my head around the definition of the $nth$ tail, which I restate from my book here:

Let $x_n$ be any sequence of real numbers. Denote $T_n = \{ x_k$ | $k \geq n \}$, which we call the $nth$ tail of the sequence $x_n$.

My problem is that the $n$ in $T_n$ seems arbitrary. For example, it seems to me like,

$\sup(T_1) = \frac{1}{2}$,

$\sup(T_2) = \frac{1}{2}$,

$\sup(T_3) = \frac{1}{4}$,

$\sup(T_4) = \frac{1}{4}$,

$\sup(T_5) = \frac{1}{6}$,

$\sup(T_6) = \frac{1}{6}$,

and so on and so forth, because $T_n$ is just $x_n$, but beginning at an $n$ of our choice instead of 1. Thus, I'm not certain what it means to find the infimum and supremum of $T_n$ in general, as opposed to a particular $T_n$, where $n$ has become definite.

So, in short, what is it that I'm missing about the definition that's causing this confusion?

Answer (score 1):

You can just write down your findings in terms of $n$:
$$
\sup T_{n}=\sup\left\{ x_{n}\colon k\geq n\right\} =\sup\left\{ \frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{k}\colon k\geq n\right\} =\begin{cases}
1/n, & \text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
1/(n+1), & \text{if }n\text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$
and similarly for the infimum.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So you're saying that I actually did understand the definition properly, and I just needed to come up with a more abstract way to express the answer?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much.